# Aligning text of options of a dropdown in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to align the 2 parts of a text of options of a dropdown in such way that one align to left and other to the right in Angular. For example, the bank name should be on left and and its type should be on right. And this has to handled using CSS.
I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```
<select class="form-control">
<option value="{{acc.id}}" *ngFor="let acc of accounts; let i=index;">{{acc.name}} <span style="float: right;" dir="rtl">{{ acc.accountType }}</span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: What doesn't work compared to what you were expecting?

Comment: i want the text in the options to be aligned in such a way that the name should be aligned on left and its type should be aligned on right